# QRCode position does not follow the results of previous output in php using library TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have a problem with position of qrcode in tcpdf.

First, I want a output of qrcode like this:

[image]

but after I added many rows inside of table, qrcode position doesn't follow with my table, like a picture below.

[image]

And this is my code

```
$style = array(
 'border' => 0,
 'vpadding' => 'auto',
 'hpadding' => 'auto',
 'fgcolor' => array(0,0,0),
 'bgcolor' => false, //array(255,255,255)
 'module_width' => 1, // width of a single module in points
 'module_height' => 1 // height of a single module in points
);
$pdf->write2DBarcode('www.tcpdf.org', 'QRCODE,Q', 0, 143, 50, 30, $style, 'N');
```

Please help me, what must I do with this problem.
With gladness, I say thank you for your help.

Comment: Try use `$barY = $pdf->GetY()` before signature, and use this variable instead 4st param (`$pdf->write2DBarcode(..., ..., ..., $barY, ..., ..., ..., ...);`).